# Checking lots of variables for truthiness in a single pass

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, truthiness, ecmascript-2020

I have a large form with many fields and a special processing function
Several variables of different types declared at the beginning of a function

I would like to check that a user has set all variables before a function execution

```js
const a1 = true, a2 = "str", a3 = { b: true }, a4 = [], a5 = "";

// Variant 1: old school
if (!(a1 && a2 && a3 && a4 && a5))
  return toast.error('Please fill out all fields');

// Variant 2: array aggregation
if (!Array.of(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5).every(Boolean))
  return toast.error('Please fill out all fields');
```

I would like to catch `a5`, since it's an empty string

Variant 1 is not readable if we have 5+ variables and not very elegant
Variant 2 is more elegant and clear but doesn't work for variables of not type Boolean

How do you check lots of variables in one pass?

Comment: `every` accepts a callback so just rewrite the function.

Comment: @Andy I was also interested in a more generalized approach for handling such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
const hasTruthyInput = v => typeof v === 'string' ? v.trim().length > 0 : Boolean(v);

// Variant 2: array aggregation
if (!Array.of(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5).every(hasTruthyInput))
  return toast.error('Please fill out all fields');
```

I used `v.trim()` to make it harder for the user to circumvent the form by entering a string full of whitespaces. Adjust to your needs.

Comment: +1 to my collection of helper functions, I was anticipating something of this nature! Will wrap it into a `useCheckTruthiness` hook for more DRY-compliancy

Comment: Glad it helped you! If this is a public site, I just hope this aggregated message does not substitute individual error messages for inputs in UI - as this wouldn't be too user friendly :)